# Get data from 2 table into 1 datagridview with condition

Tags: c#, sql, database, join

Hello this is what i have in mind but no idea how to properly do it.

```
Table1

ID   ID2     Name      Dosage
------------------------------
1    001     Name1     Dosage1
2    002     Name2     Dosage2
3    003     Name3     Dosage3


Table2

ID  Quantity   
------------------------
1   1000
2   2000
3   3000
```

Query something like:

Select ID,Name,Dosage from Table1 and Quantity(of the same ID from Table1)from Table2
where ID2 from Table1 ='002';

```
Datagridview Output

ID  Name    Dosage   Quantity
---------------------------------
2   Name2   Dosage2  2000
```

Comment: You need a join statement and then render the output into a datagridvew; which database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

A simple SQL join should work.
Try this :

```
select Table1.ID, Table1.Name, Table1.Dosage, Table2.Quantity
from Table1
inner join Table2 on Table2.ID = Table1.ID
where Table2.ID2 = '002';
```

Comment: Sir what if the ID2 is on table 1? I tried where Table1.ID2 =... but its not working.

Comment: It should work with Table1.ID2 = '002'
What does the error message say ?

Comment: "an expression of a non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'where' ". here is the actual query: string supID = "200049" -- "Select Supplier_productlist.ProductID , Supplier_productlist.Brand , Supplier_productlist.Dosage , Products.Quantity From Supplier_productlist inner join Products on Products.ProductID where Supplier_productlist.SupplierID = '" + supID + "' "

Answer (score 0):

From the comment you gave to the another answer. You should fix it to look like this:

```
DECLARE @SupID INT = 200049;

SELECT SP.ProductID, SP.Brand, SP.Dosage, P.Quantity
FROM Supplier_productlist AS SP
INNER JOIN Products AS P
ON P.ID = SP.ProductID
WHERE SP.SupplierID = @SupID;
```

In case `SupplierID` is a "string", declare it like this instead:

```
DECLARE @SupID NVARCHAR(10) = '200049';
```